# How do I reduce my sleeping time, so that I can work for longer hours?

Tags: exams

I am preparing for two tough entrance exams (the [JEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Entrance_Examination) [Main](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Entrance_Examination_%E2%80%93_Main) and JEE [Advanced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Entrance_Examination_%E2%80%93_Advanced)). Nine months remain before the exams and I have a lot of work to be done daily, such as revising my notes notes, practising problems, attending classes, making short notes, reading references, etc. I am not able to do all of that... I sleep around 9 hours and whenever **I try to reduce that to around 6‒7 hours**, I  fail at it. I am not able to concentrate in studies, I feel sleepy, and my brain stops working.

Is there any way, in which I can systematically reduce my sleeping time and improve my studies?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Exchange is not an appropriate place to solicit medical advice. Too many of the answers and comments are giving medical advice.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Life is not a sprint--it's marathon. You should rush in some issues but not always. Taking good sleep is very important to avoid some of the long-term health consequences such as hypothyroidism, obesity, skin health, and aging (Not a medical suggestions, but from experiences and what I have seen in people around me plus lots of reading scientific articles and news from reliable sources based on published literatures). So, you should create a balance.

Coming to your issue, I am assuming you are in late teen or early 20s since you are preparing for your career-building exam. I understand the rush and enthusiasm as I passed through same phase of life. At your age, 9 hours sleep seems perfectly reasonable. You have 9 months left which is plenty of time to prepare for any tough exams in the world if you manage time properly and try to understand what you are learning rather than trying to memorize. Try to be more systematic on your approach--like using stickers, wall-notes, wall posters, making cheat sheets, mini-notes, handy notes, flip cards, etc. and summarize items that you cannot understand and but must memorize. Sometime writing down what you are reading helps a lot. Also, allocate 1-2 hours for walk or run so you can refresh your mind to learn new stuffs quickly. Merely studying does not help at all to prepare for such big exams. It's about balancing reading, daily life, and sleep.

I don't think you are expecting this answer. But, I hope this is helpful to pause for a while and think about your own approach. Good luck with the exam. Please let me know after 9 months, 1) if you changed your approach or not and 2) if you succeed or not.

Comment: Also lots of data on needing good sleep to actually "set" memory. Skimping on sleep only degrades learning ability.

Comment: Let's not forget that without sleeping your brain is less efficent.

Comment: Thank you! I will try following this!

Comment: +1 for the exercise breaks.  This will also improve sleep quality.  One thing that might be an option is to do this with one or two of your peers, allowing but not forcing (except maybe close to the exams) discussion of the subject matter.  Group study can be helpful, and helping each other to think about the material without notes can be helpful.

Answer (score 13):

***No.***

That's the straightforward answer to your main question: *Is there any way , in which I can systematically reduce my sleeping time and improve my studies?* As @EarlGrey has commented, ageing is the only real option ... and unsurprisingly, it takes time!

You are more likely to study effectively in the time you are awake if you are not also sleep deprived. You might consider reading [this article](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31072563/), or at least the abstract, and some of the articles it mentions.

Answer (score 6):

There is only one our healthy and safe way to do it, and unfortunately it is not available to you: ageing.
Just wait to be older, and you will [naturally sleep less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep#Recommended_duration).

Stop counting hours, think about being more efficent, not about doing more: you cannot, even the mensa genius are not mensa genius because they study 200 hours per week.

And let's not even start about the downside of a brain&soul damaged from months of sleep deprivation, what in very unfortunate cases they do if the exams fail.

Answer (score 2):

At any age, different people need different amounts of sleep. The amount generally declines with age, but it varies at any age. Right now, you seem to need nine hours. Don't deny your body what it needs (of course, it's possible to sleep less for a night or two, but even this can have bad effects).

But .... all is not lost.

US Supreme Court Justice Felix Frankfurter is an interesting case. This was a very smart guy. Prior to SCOTUS, he was a professor at Harvard Law.

His wife once complained "do you know what it's like to be married to a man who is *never* tired?"

But, this same guy said "I can't think for more than two hours a day." You can figure he did some very good thinking in those two hours!

I would consider revising the list of things you have to do and how much time you need to do them each day. Both as a student and as a professor (briefly, while I was a grad student) I found that many students take far too many notes.  If you take that many notes, then a) it takes longer to review them and you are reviewing a lot of stuff that isn't important and b) You may not be paying as close attention to the lecture.

Answer (score 2):

Sleeping less is always discussed by everyone who hail productivity. The accepted answer does a very good job at explaining why it's not necessary to go to such extreme.

About the question itself, I'll give some insight from the point of view with someone with some insomnia/different sleep pattern and who tried to do so for some time. I'd also like to address polyphasic sleeping before someone suggest it as a miracle solution.

I looked into polyphasic sleep for 3 years during my undergrad as I always had sleep troubles. I was part of an online community of people interested in the subject and empirically "studying" it.
I have seen hundreds, likely thousand of people, join the community and ask advice on how to reduce their sleep schedule.
I have barely seen a few people get something out of it. The very few people I have seen gain additional time during their day (in the short term, without knowledge of long term consequence) were people who already had predisposition to short sleep (such as DEC2 mutation or other), medical conditions or very particular environmental pressure. That's without mentioning the very strict schedule they had to follow, down to the minute. And first, they all spent a month where their sleep quality was way lower.

And that was people being part of a community of people who tried to reduce sleep, leveraging to some extent academic study to improve their likelihood of success as well as using the empirical knowledge they gained from everyone trying and the few succeeding.

I tried to reduce my sleep as well, and remove a similar ratio of sleep time you would like to shave off, going from 6h30 to 4h30. I was very strict on my schedule, following a perfect routine. i lasted 21 days, and then sleep dept caught up to me, and I spent a day with the worst headache I ever had and ended vomiting most of the food I had. I don't advice reducing your sleep.