How do I remain more focused in studies?
Background of the Question:-
I am a JEE aspirant , and I have loads of work to do.. But now I have been observing a common trend everyday. I just dont study anymore.

I try revising stuff, but get demotivated on seeing I have forgotten
whatever I had revised so many times
I get demotivated upon seeing others working so so hard for the same exam while I am doing nothing
I keep on getting distracted

Eventually , due to constant stress ( I think this is the reason , not sure though), I have lost my  interest in studies.. and now that's posing me a problem.. I waste the entirety of my day and then fall into guilt when I am about to sleep. I want to work hard because this exam can literally change my life.
I have approximately 8 months left for the exam.. but the problem is that I have to manage my school exams in between , revise the entirety of my 11th class (That's how the education system works in our country , for those who don't know) , and prepare for this entrance exam side by side, which will be including approximately 60 + chapters , to be tested for deciding which college a student goes to.
Main Question:-
I seriously need to work hard , and I also want to , but I am lacking focus.
Please suggest something that can help me staying focused.

"I am lacking focus".   If this is severe enough that you are asking here, then: you should perhaps consult a counselor or medical professional to get a diagnosis in your particular case.

That Wikipedia article indicates the Joint Entrance Exam is for undergraduate admissions. Undergraduate admissions is unfortunately not appropriate for this site.

@Ian the main question is oriented about how to focus and study, which can be applied to any type of postgrad study as well (https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/754/undergraduate-questions). The JEE is more a context here, but the answer can be given without that in mind. It is however, a duplicate to common question I'd say

Does this answer your question? How does one remain focused while studying for the GRE?

Also you may want to look at the accepted answer of this (off-topic) question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/208625/how-do-i-reduce-my-sleeping-time-so-that-i-can-work-for-longer-hours/208658#208658 which explains how to balance studying hard with life to be efficient

Thank you @JackRed

Thank you @Anyon
